# How to know RDS free storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've created a RDS postgres instance with size of 65GB initially.
Is it possible to get free space available using any postgres query.

If not, how can I achieve the same?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A couple ways to do it

### Using the AWS Console

Go to the RDS console and select the region your database is in. Click on the **Show Monitoring** button and pick your database instance. There will be a graph (like below image) that shows **Free Storage Space**. It may be on the second or third page of graphs.

This is documented over at [AWS RDS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Monitoring.html#USER_Monitoring).

[image: Example AWS RDS console]

### Using the API via AWS CLI

Alternatively, you can use the AWS API to get the information from cloudwatch.

I will show how to do this with the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

This assumes you have set up the AWS CLI credentials. I export `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in my environment variables, but there are [multiple ways to configure the CLI (or SDKS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html).

```
REGION="eu-west-1"
START="$(date -u -d '5 minutes ago' '+%Y-%m-%dT%T')"
END="$(date -u '+%Y-%m-%dT%T')"
INSTANCE_NAME="tstirldbopgs001"

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="$REGION" aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
  --namespace AWS/RDS --metric-name FreeStorageSpace \
  --start-time $START --end-time $END --period 300 \
  --statistics Average \
  --dimensions "Name=DBInstanceIdentifier, Value=${INSTANCE_NAME}"

{
    "Label": "FreeStorageSpace",
    "Datapoints": [
        {
            "Timestamp": "2017-11-16T14:01:00Z",
            "Average": 95406264320.0,
            "Unit": "Bytes"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Using the API via Java SDK

Here's a rudimentary example of how to get the same data via the [Java AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), using the [Cloudwatch API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/AmazonCloudWatchClient.html).

#### `build.gradle` contents

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudwatch:1.11.232'
}

mainClassName = 'GetRDSInfo'
```

#### Java class

Again, I rely on the credential chain to get AWS API credentials (I set them in my environment). You can change the call to the builder to change this behavior (see [Working with AWS Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) documentation).

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatch;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.GetMetricStatisticsResult;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.StandardUnit;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.Dimension;
import com.amazonaws.services.cloudwatch.model.Datapoint;

public class GetRDSInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long GIGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;

        // calculate our endTime as now and startTime as 5 minutes ago.
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date endTime = cal.getTime();
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
        Date startTime = cal.getTime();

        String dbIdentifier = "tstirldbopgs001";
        Regions region = Regions.EU_WEST_1;

        Dimension dim = new Dimension()
            .withName("DBInstanceIdentifier")
            .withValue(dbIdentifier);

        final AmazonCloudWatch cw = AmazonCloudWatchClientBuilder.standard()
                                        .withRegion(region)
                                        .build();

        GetMetricStatisticsRequest req = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            .withNamespace("AWS/RDS")
            .withMetricName("FreeStorageSpace")
            .withStatistics("Average")
            .withStartTime(startTime)
            .withEndTime(endTime)
            .withDimensions(dim)
            .withPeriod(300);

        GetMetricStatisticsResult res = cw.getMetricStatistics(req);

        for (Datapoint dp : res.getDatapoints()) {
            // We requested only the average free space over the last 5 minutes
            // so we only have one datapoint
            double freespaceGigs = dp.getAverage() / GIGABYTE;
            System.out.println(String.format("Free Space: %.2f GB", freespaceGigs));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example Java Code Execution

```
> gradle run

> Task :run
Free Space: 88.85 GB


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 7s
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But , I want to know the size of RDS host using postgres query. Is there any query which can tell me the host disk size in postgres?

Comment: @Phani Postgres doesn’t provide this capability directly, and the RDS version of it doesn’t support untrusted language features, which would sort of allow you to write a function that could do it. You will have to use the AWS-provided mechanisms to get this information.

Comment: Thank you.. Understood.I am looking for Java SDK to give me the RDS free size.

Comment: @Phani added a Java example to the end of my answer.

Comment: Does https://i.imgur.com/XgxvjCP.png this mean we've have 3GB of remaining storage?

Comment: @RajeshChaudhary No, the graph to the left of that is your free storage space (looks like ~80-90 GB). The graph you're looking at indicates that the RDS instance has about 3 GB of freeable memory, which means it has that much memory being used for non-essential OS things, like system caches.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I also meant to draw an arrow to the left one but I don't how I drew over Memory. My Bad.

Comment: I don't see any "Free Storage Space (MB)" in the AWS Console, only "Free Storage Space (MB/Second)"

Comment: Update: in the monitoring UI you need to search for "storage", because the charts are paged, and "FreeStorageSpace" is not on the first page

Answer (score 3):

The method using the **AWS Management Console** has changed.

Now you have to go:

- RDS > Databases > [your_db_instance]
- From there, scroll down, and click on "**Monitoring**"
- There you should be able to see your db's "**Free Storage Space**" (in MB/Second)